# Combining Variable for a path

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How to combine a variable with a path search

This is what the xml look like

```
<FIELD Name="User1Transmission.DocumentID" Value=""></<FIELD
<FIELD Name="User2Transmission.DocumentID" Value=""></<FIELD
<FIELD Name="User3Transmission.DocumentID" Value=""></<FIELD
<FIELD Name="User4Transmission.DocumentID" Value=""></<FIELD
```

**Update:
After carefull check I believe the xml look as follow**

```
<FIELD>
  <NAME>User1Transmission.DocumentID</NAME>
  <VALUE></VALUE
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
  <NAME>User2Transmission.DocumentID</NAME>
  <VALUE></VALUE
</FIELD>
```

Although this is just an example, User3,4 could also not exists. Therefore I am trying to find the information according to the User.

I know for a fact I can get the information for each User this way

```
<DocumentID><xsl:value-of select="//FIELD[NAME='User1Transmission.DocumentID']/VALUE"/></DocumentID>
```

However I don't know if the value will always be there.

I created a variable count which allow me to select User1, User2, and so on, But I can't combine the variable with the path.

I try the following

```
<DocumentID><xsl:value-of select="//FIELD[NAME='User[$count]Transmission.DocumentID']/VALUE"/></DocumentID>
<DocumentID><xsl:value-of select="//FIELD[NAME='concat('User',$count,'Transmission.DocumentID')]/VALUE"/></DocumentID>
```

But they all appear to fail.

Comment: I just updated my tag xml,

Comment: That's not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<FIELDS>
    <FIELD>
      <NAME>User1Transmission.DocumentID</NAME>
      <VALUE>100</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
      <NAME>User2Transmission.DocumentID</NAME>
      <VALUE>200</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
      <NAME>User3Transmission.DocumentID</NAME>
      <VALUE>300</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
</FIELDS>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="user-number" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/FIELDS">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD[NAME=concat('User', $user-number, 'Transmission.DocumentID')]/VALUE" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>200</result>
```